# Exception when using MessageBox with CellValidating event

Tags: c#, winforms, radgridview

I am getting an exception when trying to use MessageBox within my CellValidating event. I check in the cellvalidating event if the cell has null value , I show a MessageBox and set e.Cancel=true; However the use of the MessageBox gives an exception  as follows-

> Object Reference not set to instance of object

My main aim is to prevent user from deleting the cell's value via grid edit.So, I need to throw a prompt and bring back the focus to the same cell, everytime when cell value is empty on tabbing out of the call.Any idea what might be causing this exception? Below is the code in my CellValidating event

```
 if ((columnName == "Date") && e.Value == null && e.ActiveEditor != null)
        {

            cell.Value = e.OldValue;

            MessageBox.Show("Please specify a date.", "Date Field is Required");

    e.Cancel=true;
  }
```

Below is the StackTrace for the error-

> > Application does not support just-in-time (JIT)
> >     debugging. See the end of this message for details.
> >
> > ************** Exception Text **************
> >     System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> >        at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewEditManager.EndEditCore(Boolean validate, Boolean cancel)
> >        at Telerik.WinControls.UI.BaseGridBehavior.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
> >        at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
> >        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
> >        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
> >        at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.WndProc(Message& m)
> >        at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Additional Detail-
The exception doesn't occur when I normally Tab OUt of the cell, but when I scroll to the extreme Right while my cell that I was editing prior to scrolling is still in edit mode, and while I scroll my prompt (MessageBox) shows up and on clicking Ok error is shown.

Comment: can you show the code in the CellValidating event pls, its hard to say anything like this

Comment: Thanks @GuidoG I have added the code I am using inside my CellValidating event.

Comment: Share the stacktrace if possible. I think its not the Messagebox that is causing exception.

Comment: Thanks @Prashanth Updated the StackkTrace and some additional details.Let me know if that helps

Comment: If you just want to prevent editing why not disable edit on the grid? and if it is only edit for one cell you can set the column to be read only.

Comment: Preventing editing is not the aim @YairI I want to throw a prompt if cell is empty and return focus to the same cell

Comment: @AditiChakrabarti thanks for the detail. The exception is not because of the message box. The EndEditCode function of the Telerik Control requires some data and that data is null. Please do go through the Telerik UI documentation so you many get an idea to solve the issue

Comment: Could not find any documentation for EndEditCore. If possible could you share the link please @Prashanth?

Comment: Hope this helps https://www.telerik.com/forums/nullreferenceexception-4a6181b2453b if not raise a ticket to telerik

Comment: If you step through, on what line does the exception occur?  Since you're getting a `NullReferenceException` I suspect that either `e` or `cell` is null.

Comment: The exception is occuring internally in the RadGridView . I am not getting it on any of the lines in my code. It gets thrown internally in  RadGridView @JimFell